# Variable declaring within function - looping

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I've got problems with my variables when i'm doing a function. This is just a silly example. In my code I've got a lot of variables I want to use in the function so I don't have to write function over and over again for each variable "ex1, ex2 etc.." Below here is what I want to do really simple. First check for "ex1" where it equals the declared value, then perform action (animation in real code). Then do the same for "ex2" and so on. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
<script>
var ex1 = 'frog'; //Those are not set manually. ID's in real code
var ex2 = 'pig';
var ex3 = 'horse';
var ex4 = 'bird';

var x = 0;
setInterval("call", 5000);
function call(){

    x++;

    if(('ex' + x) == 'frog'){
    //action a
    }
    else if(('ex' + x) == 'pig'){
    //action b
    }
    else if(('ex' + x) == 'horse'){
    //action c 
    }
    else if(('ex' + x) == 'bird'){
    //action d
    }

}

</script>
```

Comment: `window['ex'+x]`. There should be a duplicate.

Comment: like if(window['ex' + x] == y) ? @Zeta

Comment: I think making ex.. an array will make it easier.

Comment: Yes, `window` holds all global variables.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are properties of the `window` object (in a browser anyways). You can access properties using square bracket notation like this:

```
var ex1 = 'frog'; //Those are not set manually. ID's in real code
var ex2 = 'pig';
var ex3 = 'horse';
var ex4 = 'bird';

var x = 0;

function call(){

    x++;

    if(window['ex' + x] === 'frog'){
    //action a
    }
    else if(window['ex' + x] === 'pig'){
    //action b
    }
    else if(window['ex' + x] === 'horse'){
    //action c 
    }
    else if(window['ex' + x] === 'bird'){
    //action d
    }

}

setInterval(call, 5000);
```

However, making `ex` an array would probably be better here:

```
var ex = [];
ex[1] = 'frog'; //Those are not set manually. ID's in real code
ex[2] = 'pig';
ex[3] = 'horse';
ex[4] = 'bird';

var x = 0;

function call(){

    x++;

    if(ex[x] === 'frog'){
    //action a
    }
    else if(ex[x] === 'pig'){
    //action b
    }
    else if(ex[x] === 'horse'){
    //action c 
    }
    else if(ex[x] === 'bird'){
    //action d
    }

}

setInterval(call, 5000);
```

If you're doing this for a lot of strings, use a `switch` statement:

```
var ex = [];
ex[1] = 'frog'; //Those are not set manually. ID's in real code
ex[2] = 'pig';
ex[3] = 'horse';
ex[4] = 'bird';

var x = 0;

function call(){

    x++;
    switch(ex[x]) {
       case 'frog':
           //action a
           break;
       case 'pig':
           //action b
           break;
       case 'horse':
           //action c
           break;
       case 'bird':
           //action d
           break;
    }

}

setInterval(call, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, regarding the ifs, a more elegant approach would be to have an object containing all the actions, like this:

```
var actions = {
  frog:function(){
  //action a
  },
  pig:function(){
    //action b
  }
}
```

and then just find the action in the object and call it if found

```
var action = actions['ex' + x]
if (action) {
  action();
}
```